# The wrong 'about me' page was copied

Tags: bug, profile-page

I just created a new account on the network. But there is an *about me* which should not be there.

I edited the Stack Overflow *about me* page for only that page where I added the `#SOreadytohelp` hashtag. Now I created a new account on [programmers.SE] with the same tag.

Check now: I tried to get rid of that, but when I wanted to edit it, there was no such tag. What is going on there?

Check these two screenshots:

[image: My Profile]

[image: Here I cannot remove it]

Well, I guess when I now click on `Save changes just for this community` it will be gone, however this is a bug IMHO.

Comment: You can check out, but you can never leave! *Muahahahaha*

Comment: @Pekka웃: [meta-tag:hotel-california]